# Change the style of a Checkbox to Button style

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to change the style of the Checkbox.

Is it possible to let the checkbox look the same like the button?

Thought about adding an image to the checkbox, but don't know how to safe the button image in good quality out of Android Studio. Maybe it's possible without adding an image?

[image: Checkbox "Double" & Button 0]

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/b0"
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:insetLeft="3dp"
android:insetRight="3dp"
android:text="@string/_0"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b17"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bUnDo"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cDouble"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/cDouble"
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/drouble"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b18"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b0"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cTriple"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Appreciate every hint.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: what exactly do you mean "like a button"? what kind of behaviour do you expect from it when it is checked or unchecked?

Comment: I'd like that the checkbox (called "Double") looks like the button next to it with title "Double" instead of "0". When it's checked the next button which is clicked should multiplied by factor 2. When it's unchecked the next button which is clicked should multiplied by factor 1.

Comment: any chance a ToggleButton can serve your purpose?

Comment: of course it's possible with a toggle button. but there I have the same issue of the style, functionally there should be no problem, I am struggling with the style, that the Toggle Button or Check box looks the same like my other buttons :/

Comment: perhaps you could delineate with some illustrations of the checked and unchecked states of the button you are looking for?

Comment: probably it's possible with an ilustration, just thought it's possible without.